# VMware ESXi vSphere Client to administer multiple EXSi servers

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-esx

I've got two servers running VMware ESXi, 10.0.0.4 and 10.0.0.6.

At the moment when I'm using the vSphere Client to administer them I only log into one of those servers at a time. So if I want to admin 10.0.0.6 and I'm logged into 10.0.0.4 I've got to close the vSphere client completely and open it up again for the different server.

Please tell me how to combine the two servers so that I don't need to do this sign in/out thing anymore! I'm sure there's a way to do it, I just don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply run two instances of vSphere Client side by side.

Comment: I see, I might have to do it like that, I'd rather it all in the one instance, but I need a free solution unfortunately.

Comment: If you want 'free' then I think toggling between 2 windows is your solution.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest and best way to do this is with [vSphere](http://www.vmware.com/products/vsphere/overview.html). Depending on your deployment scenarios it [ranges from reasonable (vSphere essentials) to moderate (vSphere Enterprise Plus)](http://www.vmware.com/products/vsphere/pricing.html), but if you have a SAN and two or more ESXi servers it's fairly easy to justify the price (vMotion, High Availability, etc).

Comment: Note that you also have to license the ESXi hosts to at least Foundation level to join them to a vCenter. ESXi free can't be managed by a licensed VC.

Comment: I don't think that you can really describe virtualisation that costs more than the hardware reasonably or moderately priced.  Imagine the outrage if windows cost that much.